# Pupperteer-sharp Get innerText of Clicked element

Tags: c#, xpath, puppeteer-sharp

How do I get the inner text of an element that has been click?

```
string xplast = "//button[@id='test']";
IElementHandle last = await ((IPage)page).WaitForXPathAsync(xplast);
await last.FocusAsync();
await last.ClickAsync();
string innertext = (await last.GetInnerTextFromElement()).ToString()
```

is there a way to do something like this? string innertext = (await last.GetInnerTextFromElement()).ToString()

Comment: Doesn't the code for the previous question/answer work here as well e.g. 
 `var text = (await last.GetPropertyAsync("innerText")).RemoteObject.Value.ToString());`?

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry yes, I realized later that it's kind of same. Sometime this is just too confusing, and even it's the same answer, I just did not realize that, Sorry for this 

Answer (score 1):

I have now tested that `var text = (await last.GetPropertyAsync("innerText")).RemoteObject.Value.ToString();` works fine, at least here on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a strongly typed experience then [PuppeteerSharp.Dom](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/PuppeteerSharp.Dom) provides a set of extensions to `PuppeteerSharp`.

Install [PuppeteerSharp.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PuppeteerSharp.Dom/) from `Nuget.org` then you can use the strongly typed extensions.

```cs
// Add using PuppeteerSharp.Dom; to access WaitForXPathAsync<T>

string xplast = "//button[@id='test']";
var last = await page.WaitForXPathAsync<HtmlButtonElement>(xplast);
await last.FocusAsync();
await last.ClickAsync();
var innerText = await last.GetInnerTextAsync();
```